# Console.Clear() blinking

Tags: c#, console

```
while (true)
{
   Console.Clear();
   for (int row = 0; row < 50; row++)
   {
      for (int col = 0; col < 50; col++)
      {
        Console.Write(world[row, col]);
      }
      Console.WriteLine();
   }
      Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

I am writing a game and I have a figure, consisted of 10 characters. I want it to move in an array of characters when some of the arrow buttons is clicked. The problem is this game isn't fluid at all. When `Console.Clear()` is used , the console blinks repeatedly and this is annoying. Is there any solution to this problem? (If I don't want to use `Console.SetCursorPosition()`, because it makes it much harder to make this game).

Comment: You can try something like Console Double Buffer: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/C-Console-Double-Buffer-adc31032

Comment: why the `while(true)` here?

Comment: I was with you right up till the bit where you wrote "because it makes it much harder"! However, I would ask why you need to keep redrawing the screen anyway?

Comment: @DavidG presumably because it's a game, and stuff will be moving

Comment: @Blorgbeard Possibly, but then you only need to redraw the bits that have moved.

Comment: @DavidG That's the part that's much harder. You can't just compute a position and draw it. You have to compute a position, compare it to the previous position, then if they don't match, erase the data at the old position and redraw it at the new position. And then if the object was obscuring another object, you have to know to draw the previously obscured object... it's not as simple as you make it sound.

Comment: DavidG , I have thought about this as well , but the whole background will be moving as well. The array has for example width of 1000. And it prints at first elements from 0 to 100, then it prints from 1 to 101 and so on until it reaches 900 to 1000.

Comment: @itsme86 Where did I say it was simple?

Comment: @DavidG I inferred it from "I was with you right up till the bit where you wrote "because it makes it much harder" which sounds like you disagree with the statement.

Comment: @itsme86 That was me commenting that OP didn't want to use `SetCursorPosition` because it was harder. Programming is often very hard because that's the correct way to do something.

Comment: Well ... I guess it is my fault for you not understanding this. The background is moving as well , you can read what I said 2 replies above , so I think it is the same job with Console.Clear() except the white spaces that I have, but I don't think this will solve the problem.

Comment: Well since you are drawing every point on the screen all the time, do you even need to clear the screen?

Comment: The whole background will be moving as well. The array has for example width of 1000. And it prints at first elements from 0 to 100, then it prints from 1 to 101, then from 2 to 102 and so on until it reaches 900 to 1000, the background will me moving left , and there are different chars at different positions.

Comment: DareDev: did you see my answer below? some feedback pls!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to sum all your scene in 1 string than draw it at once, this will (hide) the blinking effect to a certain point:

```
string scene = "";

// iterate your array to construct the scene string
for (int row = 0; row < 50; row++)
{
   for (int col = 0; col < 50; col++)
   {
      scene += world[row, col];
   }
   scene += '\n'; // new line
}
Console.Clear();  // thanx David
Console.Write(scene);
```

Comment: Better to move the `Clear` to just above the `Write` too.

Comment: I would recommend use of a `StringBuilder` instead of string concatenation here.

Comment: @itsme86: definitely valid point,  I just proposed this (native) solution and the rest on the OP, I guess he will do great starting from here

Comment: Oh my god , it works ! Thank you man , thank you all so much , itsme86, DavidG and chowaib ! I am sorry I can't upvote you , I will ask my friend to do this though :) I really can't thank you enough for this.

Answer (score 2):

I've never done this myself, but you might be able to create a poor man's double buffering scheme by doubling the size of [Console.BufferHeight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.bufferheight%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). When you're ready to draw, [Console.SetCusorPosition()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) one time to the beginning of the off-screen buffer area, draw your scene like normal, and then use [Console.MoveBufferArea()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zks4cwcf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to move the freshly drawn off-screen scene to on-screen.

Answer (score 0):

Its blinking because Console.Clear() is too slow.
To speed it up, increase the buffer size with either this:

```
Console.BufferHeight = int;
Console.BufferWidth = int;
```

or this:

```
Console.SetBufferSize(width, height);
```

Comment: Another answer from many years ago notes the Buffer height change already. When posting answers, try to make sure they aren't repeating other answers to minimize noise.