# C# - Remove Flashing console contents

Tags: c#, ascii, console-application

I made a simple c# console application which can be used as a kind of graphical system (or something. it simply shows a ascii image of random colors on the screen 50 times). but I encountered a problem: The console contents are flashing. I know this is because I execute a Console.Clear() command repeatively, but how do you solve it? Someone made a 3D renderer in ascii which was way larger than the 10x32 picture sequence I have, but there you can't (or barely) see that issue.

This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            begin:
            for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < 32; x++)
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor)new Random().Next(1, 5);
                        Console.Write("\u2588");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (input == "repeat")
                goto begin;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As an aside, you should not get into the habit of using `goto` statements.  There are generally always better ways to achieve the same functionality.

Comment: possible duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28490246/console-clear-blinking

Comment: @DarrenYoung surely agree :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the goal is to keep overwriting the same image, you can reset the cursor position to the start (0,0), which will prevent the flashing caused by `Clear`ing:

```
        var rnd = new Random(); //defined the random outside the for-loop for reusing
        do //replaced the goto with a do..while
        {
            Console.Clear(); //call clear once before the main loop to reset the input
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0); //go back to the top instead of clearing

                for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < 32; x++)
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor)rnd.Next(1, 5);
                        Console.Write("\u2588");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
            Console.ResetColor();
        } while (Console.ReadLine() == "repeat");
```

Comment: Thank you! the randomness of the pixels seems to have inproved too. I will try this out with some other symbols, since these are rectangles (and not squares)